# Where is this bottom padding/margin coming from?

Tags: css

At the top of [this page](https://www.unotate.com/dev.html) in a box is my avatar. There is padding or margin below the avatar and I can't figure out where it's coming from.
[Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FC4i.png)
The developer tools in Chrome say that the image has margin and padding 0, and there is no padding set for the td element (though I've tried setting that too, to no avail). That extra space at the bottom gives the block an unbalanced look. Can anybody see what's causing it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with **clearly** stating what your desired result is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: As a general point, using tables for layout is the "old" way of doing it. By old I mean at least 10-15 years old! CSS has far better ways of achieving precise layouts than those old-fashioned tables, which are prone to this kind of head-scratcher. Tables should be used for... tables (i.e., tabulated data), not as a de-facto layout technique. By using the new flex layouts, you could have a much prettier page that would effortlessly flow to fit any sized device. This page will be almost unreadable for a mobile user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set `display: inline-grid;` property on the warping td of image.
something like `td { display: inline-grid; }` better use some class for ref of td.
In case of any query ping me :)

[screen shot bottom image space removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXs6I.png)

Comment: Thanks! That worked for the situation I gave, but now for a very similar situation it doesn't. Take a look at [this page](https://www.unotate.com/dev2.html). Again, the avatar in the upper left corner has a space below it. I added a yellow background just to make it more visible. That table cell has the same class as in the previous issue.

Any idea what's going on? Thanks you for your help!

Comment: Now you have and `a` tag aswell in `td` you need to set `display: flex` on `a` or `img` tag. Other option is to set `display: contents;` on `a` tag.

`display: contents;`—is a new display value that essentially makes the container disappear, making the child elements children of the element the next level up in the DOM.

Comment: I am in awe of your CSS knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: NP :) Welcome !

Answer (score 0):

Just joined S.O so forgive me if I didn't format this well.

The solution that I came up with is in your `.css`-file, the `img.avatar { }` block.

Just like your `th,td {}` block you need to add a `'vertical-align : middle'`.

It gets rid of the margin so it looks better.

:]